# Sending data from nodemcu to webserver

Tags: php, server, nodemcu

I'm sending data from a nodemcu to a phpMyAdmin table on a web hosted server.

I've already made a PHP script that's sending the values to the table if I input the PHP with the values in websearch. When I try to do it with my nodemcu, it connects without a struggle, but the values don't get sent.

```
void Sending_To_phpmyadmindatabase() {
 if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    Serial.print("GET /Arduino/dht.php?PHValue=");
    client.print("GET /Arduino/dht.php?PHValue=");    
    Serial.println(PHValue);
    client.print(PHValue);
    client.print("&temperature=");
    Serial.println("&temperature=");
    client.print(temperatureData);
    Serial.println(temperatureData);
    client.print(" ");      //SPACE BEFORE HTTP/1.1
    client.print("HTTP/1.1");
    client.println();
    client.println("HOST: ####");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } else {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
}
```

Comment: print the response

Comment: Println does just that if Im not completly mistaken.

Comment: the HTTP response returned by the server and received by client.read

Comment: Thank you very much Juraj but how should i do that?

Comment: if you don't know, then better use the ESP8266HTTPClient library

Comment: Am i really far of from the right answer? I Thought this was a good way so if you have any advice how i might learn that i would really appreciate that!

Comment: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/b220f3826db05f44abc3af66f7f753a70c96f437/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/WiFiWebClient/WiFiWebClient.ino

Comment: The thing is it works locally, Is that such a big difference when it all happens through a link anyways? Because it can connect with no difficulties.

Comment: This is what i get when using client.read doesnt look wrong to me                    
 WiFi connected
Server started
(LOCAL IP)connecting...
connected
GET /Arduino/dht.php?PHValue=1.00&temperature=11.00HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 12 Dec 2019 13:18:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://servername.se/Arduino/dht.php?PHValue=1.00&temperature=11.00
Content-Length: 354
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: the server accepts only https. use the WiFiClientSecure